# in Drupal 7 - Services module, custom field listing

Tags: service, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 with an AMFPHP service and want to list the contents of a custom field select list.

I have been trying to use field_info_field($field_name) but keep getting access denied for user admin.

I can't find the permissions anywhere that would allow me to access this. I can get nodes fine:

user_access("node content") and have tried all other permissions listed in the role_permission table. All permissions have been granted for the user admin...

Any ideas?

Comment: Strike that, I uninstalled and re-installed the module and it worked.